# Problemas al instalar LAMP en ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dependencias

Soy un usuario nuevo de este sistema, y tengo problemas al instalar LAMP.

*Este es mi sistema:* 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04 
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty

En primer lugar hice **sudo apt-get update** y luego **sudo apt-get install lamp-server^**. 
Me devuelve el error:

> No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
>   usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
>   inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
>   han sacado de «Incoming».
>   
> La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:
>   
>  Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
>    perl-modules-5.22 : Entra en conflicto: perl-modules
>                        Entra en conflicto: perl-modules:i386

Para tratar de corregir el error hice **sudo clean** y **sudo autoremove**, y luego repito **sudo apt-get install lamp-server^**, y vuelve a aparecer el error.

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme con esto. Gracias.

Comment: Para qué sirve el carácter `^`?

Comment: Si no lo uso, me dice que el paquete es inexistente... Existe otro comando para instalarlo?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/401431/e-unable-to-locate-package-lamp-server

Comment: $ sudo tasksel install lamp-server, me retorna:
tasksel: apt-get failed (100)

Comment: Luego de **sudo apt-get update** retorna:
>W: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-team/ppa/ubuntu zesty Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: Los datos de un repositorio como este no se pueden autenticar...
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: Fallo al obtener http://ppa.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/source/Sources  404
E: No se han podido descargar algunos archivos de índice

Comment: Se que no preguntas esto, pero lamp-server es un metapaquete y por tanto debe existir, igual no existe, prueba a usar apt-cache search lamp para ver los resultados de paquetes que sí existen. Pero si no quieres darle muchas vueltas, tu problema se soluciona instalando phpmyadmin, ya que requiere apache, mysql y php que es lo que instalas con lamp. Para instalar phpmyadmin: sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

Comment: Gracias. Voy a intentar

Comment: @track3r seguí tu sugerencia, y me encuentro con: dpkg: error al procesar el paquete phpmyadmin (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 10
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Parece que hay algún problema de conflictos o similar. Prueba primero apt-get install -f y luego apt-get install phpmyadmin

Comment: Lo solucioné descargando el phpmyadmin. Gracias. SOLUCIONADO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 17.04 es un paquete estándar,y ya no está recibiendo actualizaciones.

> [Copia del anuncio Oficial, traducido.]  
>  Ubuntu anunció su
>   lanzamiento de 17.04 (Zesty Zapus) hace casi 9 meses, en 13 de abril
>   de 2017. Como versión no LTS, 17.04 tiene un ciclo de soporte de 9
>   meses y, como tal, alcanzará el final de la vida el sábado, 13 de
>   enero.

En ese momento, los avisos de seguridad de Ubuntu ya no incluirán información o
paquetes actualizados para Ubuntu 17.04.

Por favor mire el anuncio oficial.

- [*Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus) reached End of Life on January 13, 2018*](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/01/17/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus-reached-end-of-life-on-january-13-2018/)

Recomiendo que utilices una Versión LTS: 
Las versiones de Ubuntu LTS (soporte a largo plazo) son compatibles por cinco años tanto en el escritorio como en el servidor. Durante ese tiempo, tiene correcciones de seguridad y otras actualizaciones críticas.